# efficienct SQL join for a range on large table

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, memory-efficient

```
    table1                            table2                   
    id      number                   start    end    indicator
    11      4                         1        5        N
    22      6                         2        7        N  
    33      8                         5        12       Y
    44      10
```

What would be the most efficient way to join these tables if I want the rows from 
table1 that correspond within the range of table2 (start,end) where the indicator is Y for two seperate conditions;

1. Only one row in table2 will have a Y indicator
2. One or more rows in table2 will have a Y indicator

ie (bad example)

```
SELECT * from table1
WHERE table1.number > (SELECT start from table2 WHERE indicator = 'Y')
AND   table1.number < (SELECT end from table2 WHERE indicator = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t2.indicator = 'Y'
and t1.number1 > t2.start
and t1.number1 < t2.end
```

Depending of your data, you may be interested to use parallel query http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/optimops.htm#PFGRF94608

Comment: Just in case there are multiple overlapping ranges and you don't want to risk duplicate hits, you may want to use `DISTINCT t1.*`

Comment: In the case of table1 having millions of rows, and being hit quite frequently, since that method of join creates a Cartesian product, is there a better method of joining for performance (assuming one Y indicator)?

Comment: @user2210179 If you get a cartesian from this, the optimizer seems to do a _very_ bad job (and I doubt Oracle does). You can always rewrite it as a regular join `SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t2.indicator = 'Y'
 AND t1."number" > t2.start
 AND t1."number" < t2.end;` but it gives the same plan.

Comment: Your table2 has only one line with indicator='Y' (and hopefully have index on it), so not really cartesian product here. 
@Joachim At the end, it will be just one big (or huge) table scan applying condition to each row comming from 1 line of table2.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1
cross join (
      select start, end from table2 where indicator='Y') B
where table1.number > B.start and table1.number
```

Answer (score 0):

If table1 is very large then the most effective method will be to turn the query into an equijoin so that you get a hash join between the data sets.

```
with table2_new as (
  select     start + rownum - 1 id
  from       table1
  where      indicator = 'Y'
  connect by level <= (end - start) +1)
select
  table1.id,
  table1.number
from
  table1,
  table2_new
where
  table1.id = table2_new.id;
```

Not tested it, but used that technique before.